# Excel date increments next month based on another date

Tags: excel

I have an overly complicated spreadsheet to show when employees have taken leave from dates in a table. It behaves differently based on if today is before or after their anniversary date. There are no macros, I'd like to keep it that way.

Currently:

```
Cell A1 = Today()
cell A2 = date pulled from a table, displayed as 01/01/20
```

I'm trying to have Cell A1 display the first of next months date if the date in cell A2 is the current month. This would push my calendar into the next years schedule. It is April, if an employee's anniversary is in April I would like A1 to show 5/1/20.

So, if A2 is not the current month, A1 shows Today(). If A2 is the current month, A1 shows the first day of the next month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
=IF(TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyyMM")=TEXT(A2,"yyyyMM"),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1),TODAY())
```

Comment: This is very close, however if the date in A2 is 4/7/2008, it displays the date in A1 as 4/12/2020. I was able to combine your answer with the if statement below to work correctly! =IF(MONTH(N2)=MONTH(TODAY()),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1),TODAY())

Comment: Well, a date in 2008 is not in the current month. You asked for the current month. Now I realise you don't want that at all. You want the calendar month, regardless of the year.

Comment: My fault for sure, I'll try to give better examples and more information next time. Thanks for the answer provided, in the end it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the situation you present, this is I think the formula you need to use in A1:

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)=MONTH(TODAY()),EDATE(A2,1),TODAY())
```

so, we have:

- If A2 month is the Current Month: `MONTH(A2)=MONTH(TODAY())`
- Then use the next month first date: `EDATE(A2,1)`
- Otherwise use Today's date: `TODAY()`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, I think this will do what I was looking for! Unfortunately I was laid off for 3 months after I posted this, so I'll have to see when I get called back to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EricMoe I'm happy this helped you and that I was useful. May you kindly accept the answer to help other having the same question as yours and vote for it to help me in return :)

Comment: I was able to find an old copy and try this formula, it's on the right track but not quite what I need. The if/then statement is likely correct, but I need this to display the next month of the current year. For example if the anniversary date is 4/7/2008, I need it to display 4/7/2020